# How to get a list of all methods decorated with `@property`?

Tags: python

How to get a list of all methods of a class which have been decorated with the `@property` decorator?

Having the following example, the answer should get a list with only `x` and `y` included, but not `z`, since it hasn't been decorated with `@property`:

```py
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None
        self._y = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    def z(self):
        pass
```

Comment: It might be helpful to provide the *context* - the whole point of properties is that it doesn't matter whether it's a vanilla attribute or a property, so what are you writing that needs to check this? On the class, or an instance?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks for pointing to this ambiguity. The context ist the class as stated: "How to get a list of all methods of a class"

Comment: That still doesn't explain *why*, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: What do you mean with "explain *why*"?

Comment: Which of the two words is confusing? Provide an explanation as to the reason. Furnish a justification for the requirement. What are you writing that cares which methods are decorated?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'm just interested in getting the properties. Please accept the question as stated. See the answers by L3viathan and theausome below.

Comment: Note that this is to avoid people wasting their time solving an http://xyproblem.info. In the future, please provide context. Also provide what you've tried that failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods decorated by `@property` are instances of `property`:

```
>>> [name for name in dir(C) if isinstance(getattr(C, name), property)]
['x', 'y']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
k = [name for name, value in vars(C).items() if isinstance(value, property)]
```

Now, `print k`

Prints: `['x', 'y']`